# Does the "ccmath" library compile on x86-64 linux?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

Ccmath library:
http://freecode.com/projects/ccmath

It does not specify `32/64 bit` in description, but when I compile on Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit it spits out error on asm-file compilling:

> solv.s:13: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

code line: `pushl %ebp`

But if I replace `cc` shell instruction for `gcc -m32` its all OK!
However, can I compile it on `x86-64`? I have to link this to 64bit project.

Comment: @Alan Curry & hims056:
Thank you, my friends!

Comment: **I finally launched it on my 64bit Ubuntu with Intel processor !!!**

Correct sequence of actions for **ccmath** compilling:

1. Start non_intel.sh, set "no" for answer (about bit order). It will compile only ".c" file without ".s".

2. Edit makelibs.sh. You should add the flag "-fPIC" to all strings with "cc -03". Like this "cc -fPIC -c -O3 *.c".

3. Start makelibs.sh.

4. Start install.sh.

Then you can build normally our **mcalib** by **scons** command.
PS **sudo ./mcalib** or change usb port may help you :)

Keywords: huey pantone mcalib ccmath linux ubuntu 64 bit intel compile error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ccmath package looks like it hasn't been updated since 2001. Its assembly routines are not 64-bit capable. You should run the included `non_intel.sh` script as instructed in the INSTALL file. (As far as this package is concerned, x86-64 is non-intel because "intel" means "x86-32".)